# Responsive JQGrid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, jqgrid

I have a system that use a side menu and JQGrid. With my monitor, I get the menu and the Grid as shown in the image below (The boxes at the left are the options of the menu):

[image]

When I resize the window or I lower the screen resolution, the JQGrid is messed up,and I get this:

[image]

How can I get the JQGrid near to the menu without messing it up? I have been investigating, and I know that making it responsive is the answer, but I'm not sure how to apply it here

The menu is applied dynamically, it have the, as shown below:

```
    <link href="../drop-down-menu/css/helper.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/drop-down-menu/css/dropdown/dropdown.vertical.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="/drop-down-menu/css/dropdown/themes/flickr.com/default.ultimate.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <ul id="nav" class="dropdown dropdown-vertical">
        <?php            
            foreach($menuhtml as $lineamenuhtml){
                echo $lineamenuhtml;
            }
        ?>
    </ul>
```

The styles used by the JQGrid are (Twitter Bootstrap is included):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/css/flick/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/jqgrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css" />
<link href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
```

Autoedit is set to true and shrinkToFit is set to false on the JQGrid

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to use the setGridWidth client-side method of jqGrid and set it to the size of the page when the page is loaded (e.g. in the document.ready event). Sample code for this approach:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var pageWidth = $(window).width();
    jQuery("#GridID").setGridWidth(pageWidth);
});
```

To do the actual resizing, a function implementing the following logic is bound to the window's resize event:

- Calculate the width of the grid using its parent's clientWidth and
  (if that is not available) its offsetWidth attribute.
- Perform a sanity check to make sure width has changed more than x
  pixels (to work around some application-specific problems
- Finally, use setGridWidth() to change the grid's width

Here is example code to handle resizing:

```
jQuery(window).bind('resize', function() {

    // Get width of parent container
    var width = jQuery(targetContainer).attr('clientWidth');
    if (width == null || width < 1){
        // For IE, revert to offsetWidth if necessary
        width = jQuery(targetContainer).attr('offsetWidth');
    }
    width = width - 2; // Fudge factor to prevent horizontal scrollbars
    if (width > 0 &&
        // Only resize if new width exceeds a minimal threshold
        // Fixes IE issue with in-place resizing when mousing-over frame bars
        Math.abs(width - jQuery(targetGrid).width()) > 5)
    {
        jQuery(targetGrid).setGridWidth(width);
    }

}).trigger('resize');
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Of course you can bind the resize function to another contaner within your aplication